# Optional Url params in nestjs swagger

Tags: swagger, nestjs

This is my code:

```
        @Get('/get-presigned-url/:extension?')
  async getS3PresignedUrl(@Param('extension') extension?: string): Promise<AwsTempPostUrlDto> {
    return await this.aws.getTemporaryPostUrl(extension);
  }
```

But the extension in the swagger is required.
[image]
How can I set url params as optional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use @Query instead of @Param